# cycle with JSON

Tags: java, json

Good afternoon,

I have a servlet where I want to convert a Json list.

I use the following code

```
List<Reunion> lista_reuniones = facadeReunion.getServidoresTareas();

        JSONArray mJSONArray = JSONArray.fromObject(lista_reuniones);
```

in lista_reunion I store objects of type Reunion

When I run the code the following error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() para servlet reunionServlet lanzó excepción
>   net.sf.json.JSONException: There is a cycle in the hierarchy!
>       at net.sf.json.util.CycleDetectionStrategy$StrictCycleDetectionStrategy.handleRepeatedReferenceAsObject(CycleDetectionStrategy.java:97)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:857)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:192)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2774)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._setInternal(JSONObject.java:2798)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1507)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:940)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:192)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONArray._processValue(JSONArray.java:2557)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONArray.processValue(JSONArray.java:2588)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONArray.addValue(JSONArray.java:2575)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromCollection(JSONArray.java:1082)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:145)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2749)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._setInternal(JSONObject.java:2798)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1507)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:940)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:192)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2774)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._setInternal(JSONObject.java:2798)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1507)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:940)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:192)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2774)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._setInternal(JSONObject.java:2798)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1507)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:940)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:192)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2774)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._setInternal(JSONObject.java:2798)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1507)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:940)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:192)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONArray._processValue(JSONArray.java:2557)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONArray.processValue(JSONArray.java:2588)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONArray.addValue(JSONArray.java:2575)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromCollection(JSONArray.java:1082)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:145)
>       at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:127)
>       at servlet.ReunionServlet.doPost(ReunionServlet.java:176)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Do you know where is the problem? If it's any help, the diagram of the database is as follows:

[image]

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Organizacion to Reunion is One-to-Many relation. If it is bi-directional relation than it can form a cyclic reference which can cause this type of exception.

I had the same type of problem when serializing my beans using Jackson. As I was using Hibernate in my project at that time.

You can avoid this problem by using Jackson for serializing and using @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference annotation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem occurred because some attributes in my entity are Lazy (JPA).

To solve, i included a jsonConfig with this instruction:

```
JsonConfig jsonConfig = new JsonConfig();
jsonConfig.setExcludes(new String[]{"files", "createdBy", "lastUpdatedBy"});
jsonConfig.setIgnoreDefaultExcludes(false);
jsonConfig.setCycleDetectionStrategy(CycleDetectionStrategy.LENIENT);

JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(obj, config);
```

This works well to me. ;-)